# I want to load a get.php file in iframe on index.html once the Submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

Ok so I'm facing this problem here
I've got 2 files :

1. `index.html`
2. `get.php`

On `index.html` I've got a form :

```
<form method="POST" action="get.php">
    <input name="x" placeholder="first value" type="text">
    <input name="y" placeholder="second value" type="text">
    <input value="send" type="submit">
</form>
<br>
<iframe id="frame" class="right" width="100%" height="300" src="get.php"></iframe>
```

and here is the `get.php` file

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['x'])==false)
{
    echo "<h3>First variable is required...</h3>";
    exit;
}

if(isset($_POST['y'])==false)
{
    echo "<h3>Second variable is required...</h3>";
    exit;
}

echo "<a style='padding:15px;background:#eee;color:#fff;border-radius:5px;' href='index.html'>Go back to the main page</a><br><br><br>";
$x=0;
$y=0;
$x=$_POST["x"];
$y=$_POST["y"];

echo "Values entered were $x and $y respectively<br><br><br>";
echo "Sum of $x+$y= ".($x+$y)."<br><br>";
echo "Multiplication of $x*$y= ".($x*$y)."<br><br>";
echo "Division of $x/$y= ".($x/$y)."<br><br>";
echo "Power of of $x<sup>$y</sup>= ".pow($x,$y)."<br><br>";
echo "power of $y<sup>$x</sup>= ".pow($y,$x)."<br><br>";

echo "Table of $x<br><br>";

for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
    echo "$x * $i = ".($x*$i)."<br>";
}

echo "<br><br>Table of $y<br><br>";
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
    echo "$y * $i = ".($y*$i)."<br>";
}

?>
```

Now what is needed is that I put 2 values in both fields and once I click the submitted button it should show result of the `get.php` in the `<iframe>` placed on `index.html` rather then loading a new page of `get.php`

Comment: how did you reach the assumption that when you submit a form a iframe should refresh?

Comment: you would perhaps be better using a javascript function ( probably with ajax ) to submit the data to `get.php` and update the iframe with the callback function

Comment: And how may I do that??

Comment: Well I reached this assumption because its one of the requirements we have ,, and as there is never a No in programming so Im pretty sure there is always a way out

Answer (score 0):

You could set iframe content using following snippet. The data are send using ajax and you need to prevent `form` submit behaviour. Try e.g:

```
$(function() { // document ready handler
  $('form[action="get.php"]').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
      var iframeDoc = $('#frame')[0].contentDocument;
      iframeDoc.open();
      iframeDoc.write(data);
      iframeDoc.close();
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Used this but Nothing is happening
Can you please give me an edited version of my code
Its really very important for me

Comment: It works as i tested it. I have no idea how you are using it... Just be sure to use `$('#frame')[0].contentDocument;` i made a previous mistake using `$('#iframe')[0].contentDocument;`... That's said, if it is your issue, then at least it should have a error in console so... And btw, i have no idea how do you debug it. Is submit event at least fired? Etc...

Comment: Problem solved Thank you
Now just onething I want to ask 
When we do CTRL+U it displays your webpage code
Could you please tell me how to display webpage code in iframe dynamically